# Argument Labels Error

Tags: swift, swift3

Getting an argument Labels error after conversion to Swift:
**Argument labels '(bytes:, length:)' do not match any available overloads**

On the payload assignment:
`let payload = Data(bytes: bytes, length: length)`

```
        if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(CBUUID(string: TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)) {
            print("Writing to characteristic \(characteristic)")
            let zpl: String = "^XA^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDHELLO WORLD^FS^XZ"
            let bytes = zpl.utf8
            let length: size_t = (zpl.characters.count ?? 0)

            let payload = Data(bytes: bytes, length: length)
            print("Writing payload: \(payload) length of \(length)")
            //peripheral.writeValue(payload, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse)
            peripheral.writeValue(payload, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType)
        }
```

And the following:

`textview.text = String(data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)`

```
    if (stringFromData == "EOM") {
        // We have, so show the data,
        textview.text = String(data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        // Cancel our subscription to the characteristic
        peripheral.setNotifyValue(false, for: characteristic)
        // and disconnect from the peripehral
        centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
    }
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `zpl.data(using: .utf8)` to convert the `String` to `Data`?

Comment: @FelixSFD =) probably because I am pretty new Felix. I will look at that.  Thank you for the suggestion.  Learning a lot from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the docs or use autocomplete in Xcode, you'll find a `bytes:count:` version of the method.  Perhaps you want something like:

```
let zpl: String = "^XA^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDHELLO WORLD^FS^XZ"
var bytes = zpl.utf8

let payload = Data(bytes: &bytes, count: zpl.characters.count)
```

Comment: It compiles ... but try that with some string and then `print(payload as NSData)` – you'll be surprised.

Comment: Yep that is it!.. The change from `length` to `count` gets me every time when I convert something!  Thank you

Comment: Phillip. Any suggestions on the `textview.text = String(data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)`

Comment: @MartinR - I didn't try to analyze the sense of the OP's code.  I was more interested in providing an approach to the type of problem.

Comment: Your version passes the *address* of `bytes` (which is a `struct String.UTF8View`) to the constructor, *not* the UTF-8 bytes. Also the .utf8 view and the .characters view can have a different count.

Comment: @JLanders: Lookup `String` in the Swift Standard Library documentation. Which constructor takes a `Data` argument? What are the parameters called? You can also try auto-completion.